# how to find if a particular point exists between two concentric circles or not???i have 3 points given on each circle

Tags: math, geometry

i have two concentric circles and three points are given for each circle that are on circumference.
I need a optimized method to check if a given random point exist inbetween these circles or not.

Comment: What work have you done on this problem so far and just where are you stuck? Have you developed a non-optimized way to solve this problem? Will one or both of the circles be fixed for multiple problems like this, so auxiliary values could be pre-calculated and stored?

Comment: i have a solution ,but it takes up more time and processor. I found the equation of both the circles using the 3 points given and applied the below formula to check if its outside the circle or inside, if the given point is outside the inner circle and inside the outer circle, then it is in between those two circles . the formula is (x-h)^2+ (y-k)^2= R^2

Comment: I don't mean to be insulting, but you have shown only the easiest part of the problem. How do you find the center and radius of each circle, or alternatively how do you find the equation of each circle? If you show us your method or code we may be able to optimize it for you. As it is now you have not shown us that you actually have any code for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute (x²+y²), x, y, 1 for each point. The last entry is simply the constant one. Put these terms for four given points into a matrix and compute its determinant. The determinant will be zero if the points are cocircular. Otherwise the sign will tell you which point is on which side with respect to the circle defined by the other three. Use a simple example to check which sign corresponds to which direction. Be prepared for the fact that the three circle-defining points being oriented in a clockwise or counter-clockwise orientation will affect this sign, too.

Computing a 4×4 determinant can be done horribly inefficiently, too. I'd suggest you compute all the 2×2 minors from the first two rows, and all the 2×2 minors from the last two, then you can combine them to form the full determinant. See [this Math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/599456/35416) for details. If you need further *mathematical* help (as opposed to programming help), you might find more suitable answers there.

Nothe that the above works for each circle independently. Check whether the point is inside the one, then check whether it is outside the other. It does not make use of the fact that the circles are assumed to be cocircular.